Existing solution for generating high-frequency digital waveforms on GPIO in Linux
We're transitioning from embedded firmware to Linux development and have a specific requirement: we need to generate a digital waveform (a sequence of 1s and 0s) on a GPIO pin at a specific frequency between 10KHz-500KHz using DMA. We're using the STM32MP131 chip.
While we're aware that we can create a custom kernel driver to achieve this, we're curious if there's a pre-existing, more general-purpose solution. A digital waveform generator seems like a versatile tool that could be useful in many scenarios.
Does anyone know of such a driver or module? A similar driver we could leverage as a starting point? Or perhaps a more efficient approach to generate digital waveforms on Linux?
We have looked at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers but didn't find anything that suited our needs.

Depending on your hardware you can use the pwm driver + device tree configuration to configure and output a waveform using the on chip PWM hardware. You can find a list of mainline PWM drivers here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/pwm . Once you have the driver in, supporting hardware, and the electronics correct, then you can write out to the corresponding files around /sys/class/pwm/ to configure the period and set your duty cycle. The last project I did with this was to link a GPIO pin and a timer channel to get PWM out on the GPIO pin.
I know it's not what you asked but you can hook the DAC pins together with the DMA to play the output waveform via DMA. Here is the application note. https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an3126-audio-and-waveform-generation-using-the-dac-in-stm32-products-stmicroelectronics.pdf
Edit 1:
Thank you for the hardware info in the edit, I have used the STM32MP157C fairly extensively for the last few years myself. Something like this might be useful. https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-software/libiio?rev=1700088641
https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-software/libiio_internals
Chapter 15 and 16 cover the MDMA and DMA
https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0475-stm32mp13xx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mpus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

We would prefer to use DMA with GPIO, does something like that already exist?

Its hard for me to say without understanding the application better. How fast does the frequency output change? What is the source that is giving the output frequency? For the digital waveform generator does it need to output only square waves or does it need to output triangle and sine waves, etc?

"We would prefer to use DMA with GPIO" - That's wishful thinking. The typical DMA controller and GPIO controller are not designed to interact.
